# How to get the Index of signed in Google account in Laravel Socialite?

Tags: laravel, oauth, google-signin, laravel-socialite

I have a Laravel application which uses Socialite for Sign In With Google functionality. The authentication part works fine and the attributes such as email, avatar, name etc. are loaded correctly. I have a few links to other google services in the app such as Google Drive and Google Meet. When these links are used, they try to access the drive file or meet using the default google account on their browser `authuser=0 or /u/0/`, but I want it to use the index of the account with which they have signed in to the Laravel app, for example `authuser=1 or /u/1/`. Can I retrieve the index of the signed in user during sign in? I can store this and use it to generate the right URLs.